# Logstash output to AlienVault (OSSIM)

Tags: logstash, ossim

I have the following topology:

rsyslog clients -> logstash server -> elasticsearch & another logstash & alienvault & local file

The problem is that alienvault wants just the raw message, without any json fields. How could i send only to alienvault just the value of the "message" field?

Until now i have made something like this:
- in logstash, in filter i have configured clone { clones => ["alien"] }.
- all the remaining filtering is above this line
- after all the other filtering i have something like...if [type] == "alien" -> mutate -> remove_field (all the fields except for the [type];
- in logstash output i have if [type] == "alien" udp { host, port, etc}

But AlienVault still receives something like this:

**Aug 31 17:01:41  {"message": "Aug 31 09:01:35 bkp1 sshd[10538]: Connection from  port ","type":"alien"}**

and i want AlienVault to receive just **"Aug 31 09:01:35 bkp1 sshd[10538]: Connection from  port "**

Is this possible with logstash?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after two days i finally figured out (in case anyone else needs this).
So this is the output for AlienVault:

tcp {
        host => ""
        port => ""
        message_format => "%{message}"
        codec => line { format => "%{message}" }
    }

P.S. I think you need it to be tcp because you need that "message_format" which is not available on the udp output.